# Agrupar valores distintos de dos columnas

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo un df tal que así

```
(df <- data.frame (var1 = c(100,100,100,200,200,200,200,300,300,300,300,300,300,400,400),
                   var2 = c(100,100,200,220,NA,200,NA,300,300,300,300,300,300,400,400)))
```

```
   var1 var2
1   100  100
2   100  100
3   100  200
4   200  220
5   200   NA
6   200  200
7   200   NA
8   300  300
9   300  300
10  300  300
11  300  300
12  300  300
13  300  300
14  400  400
15  400  400
```

Quiero pasar a una tabla aquellos de var1 que difieran de var2 contando el numero de elementos
que hay.

Por ejemplo

```
grupo<-group_by(df,var1,var2)
(tabla <- summarise(grupo, n= n()))
```

```
    var1  var2     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1   100   100     2
2   100   200     1
3   200   200     1
4   200   220     1
5   200    NA     2
6   300   300     6
7   400   400     2
```

hay seis 300 y dos 400 en las dos tablas,  esos no me interesan, me interesan los que son diferentes, es decir, el 100 y el 200.

Ahora tendría que hacer una transformación para dejar la tabla anterior como la siguiente, donde aparecen todos los valores de 100 y 200 en var2

```
    var1  var2     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1   100   100     2
2   100   200     1
3   200   200     1
4   200   220     1
5   200    NA     2
```

He probado usando duplicated pero no consigo sacar dicha tabla.

Comment: ¿Y cual es la condición para filtrar esas observaciones? ¿que no sean 300 o 400 en ambas variables?

Comment: 300 , 400 o cualquier otro numero que tenga el mismo valor en la otra columna. Por ejemplo partiendo de "tabla" lo que quiero quitar son las filas que tienen el mismo contenido en var1 que en var2. ej: 100 en var1 tiene 100 y 200 en var2, No lo quito. Lo quitaria si solo tuviera 100 en var2.      300 en var 1 solo tiene 300 en var2. Lo quito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que usas `dplyr`, con:

```
df %>% 
  count(var1, var2) %>% # Contamos las combinaciones de var1 y var2
  count(var1) %>%       # var1 cuantas veces se repiten
  filter(n == 1)        # filtramos las que aparecen una sola vez

  var1 n
1  300 1
2  400 1
```

Obtenemos las filas que queremos quitar, y finalmente para hacerlo, usamos un `anti_join()` que nos traerá las filas que no coinciden con la consulta anterior.

```
df %>% 
  count(var1, var2) %>% 
  anti_join(df %>% 
              count(var1, var2) %>% 
              count(var1) %>% 
              filter(n == 1),
            by = "var1")

  var1 var2 n
1  100  100 2
2  100  200 1
3  200  200 1
4  200  220 1
5  200   NA 2
```